# Prevent SD card corruption / Create read-only root FS (overlayroot)

Tags: raspberry-pi, root-filesystem, overlayfs

I'm looking to prevent sd card corruption on an OrangePI Zero 2 running Debian.
I thought the best way is to have a readonly fs, so I tried following the instructions [here](https://blog.zackmarvel.com/read-only-root-filesystem-on-a-debian-buster-system.html), but it failed on the following step:

```
$sudo mount -o move /etc /mnt/etc/
mount: /mnt/etc/root-ro: bad option; moving a mount residing under a shared mount is unsupported.
```

My goal is to prevent sd card corruption.

1. Is there a better way of creating a readonly fs?
2. Are there other options of reducing corruption? e.g. automatically running `fsck` on each boot? Can disabling journaling help? Anything else?

Hardware: OrangePi Zero 2
OS: Debian (official `Orangepizero2_3.0.6_debian_bullseye_server_linux5.16.17`)
If sound and gpio work good on Ubuntu I can move to that OS (unfortunately sound and gpio seem to be problematic on Armbian).

I'm a "simple" programmer and not familiar with mounting/fs/overlay - Any help is very much appreciated!

Here is info of the various mounts:

```bash
$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename    Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/zram0  partition   503864  0       5


$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=5dd5b836-fb32-4678-908e-d23f7a028780 / ext4 defaults,noatime,commit=600,errors=remount-ro 0 1
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid 0 0


$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            422M     0  422M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  836K   98M   1% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p1   30G  2.1G   27G   8% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /tmp
/dev/zram1       49M   18M   28M  39% /var/log
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0


$ blkid
/dev/mmcblk1p1: UUID="5dd5b836-fb32-4678-908e-d23f7a028780" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e8ce0794-01"
/dev/zram0: UUID="0d318608-f97b-49cb-ad9a-2868d4158952" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram1: LABEL="log2ram" UUID="7c3c126a-be5d-491c-89be-a59ce9d002a8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Read-Only filesystem does not prevent your SD card from dying. Updates will not be possible without remounting root partition as writable, this is a big drawback in some scenarios. What you can do is investigate where your applications are writing to and point them to tmpfs. You may also enlarge tmpfs partition.

Still, I think you would need an off-the shelf solution, and it is what [DietPi](https://dietpi.com/) does. It is a minimal OS, with SD longevity in mind, by default writes log to RAM. I had my RBPi 4 two years 24x7 without any problem so far.

The log in RAM feature I think is provided by `log2ram`. You may put out of SD most of write requests with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to overlayroot and have been looking for an easy way to set it up in my pet project on orange pi zero 2.

I found a [good version of the instructions](https://gist.github.com/probonopd/97f6826cc5aa3c0c0950682b0bc266bc#make-it-read-only) only for ubuntu. For debian there was also an attempt to use the overlayroot package, but as far as I understand, other solutions or workarounds need to be used there.

Run the following commands only for Ubuntu based Armbian (official Ubuntu for orange pi zero 2 is also suitable)

```
sudo apt update
apt-get remove unattended-upgrades
mv /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily.DISABLED
apt-get install overlayroot
echo 'overlayroot="tmpfs"' > /etc/overlayroot.conf
```

Use overlayroot-chroot to make edits to the system:

```
cd /media/root-ro
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount -t sysfs sys sys/
mount -o bind /dev dev/
overlayroot-chroot
```

Check and minimize space in RAM used by overlay files

```
df -h /media/root-rw
rm -rf /media/root-rw/overlay/var/
```